# Do covert op ship sensor types have any effect on the sites they can scan down?

Tags: eve-online

Do covert ops, like Anathema, etc, ship's sensor types have any effect on their ability to scan down sites? Is a ship with radar sensors able to scan down radar sites more easily than gravimetric or similar?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a bit misleading, but sensor strength of your ship has nothing to do with how well you can scan down anything. It affects two things:

- How resistant you are to being jammed by ECM
- How easy it is to scan *you* down

The important parameter for scanning is the sensor strength *of the probe* (which isn't classified as gravimetric, ladar, radar, ...), and there are several factors that can increase this:

- T1 scanning frigate (5% per level) or T2 covert ops bonus (10% per level) and your skill with that ship
- The Astrometric Rangefinding skill
- T1, T2 or Sister's Probe launcher
- Regular or Sister's Scanner probes